# Why Code coverage ribbon is not visible on Source editor?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I have integrated Unit test in my project.

> - I have enabled code coverage from Xcode->Editor->CodeCoverage.
> - From App schemes-> Test->Options->Checked Gatherd coverage for my app target.

[image: Code Coverage Enabled]

[image: Scheme enabled]

[image: No Code Coverage]

As you can see in above image i have added unit test cases for class DemoTestFile but ribbon shows empty.

I have also filed here https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/8915292

Answer (score 1):

You have to run tests `Product->Test`. If the `test` action is not enabled that means that your test cases are not enabled in `Edit scheme` -> `Test` -> `Info`.

Comment: Yes i already did. Test was success. But No code coverage ribbon.

Comment: change the option some targets to all targets

Comment: Create a new empty project with default configuration for a unit test target and test it. What's your Xcode version?

Comment: What are your `general`settings for your unit test target? Host Application None?

Comment: `general` ? Can you please specific ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225147/discussion-between-blazej-sleboda-and-jack).

Comment: by upgrading xcode to 12.3 its fixed. :) Thanks blazej